# Visual Studio Error code for required field

Tags: vs-code

I am new to VS code and I am trying to make a field required, I have basically made it required on the object and created the branch in Soruce Tree but I am getting this error when I try to push it.

You cannot deploy to a required field: Objcet_Name.Field__c

do I need to make the field visible to all profiles?

Thanks,
Lorr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined the field as required you do not need to make it visible to all Profiles but rather remove the FLS metadata for that field for all the Profiles, as it will be readable and accessible by default.

Comment: Thank you for the response, that makes sense.